# How to override or change function in form.php in a plugin

Tags: functions

I have a file in a plugin named `form.php`. I know that to make what I want to work I just need to change 1 line of code at `$taxonomies = wp_dropdown_categories` in this function below and add a parameter of `depth => 1` into that line of code in this function.

```
private function taxonomy_select_field($field = array()) {
    if ( isset( $field['label'] ) ) {
        $this->label();
    }

    $this->output .= '<div class="ap-form-fields-in">';

    $taxonomies = wp_dropdown_categories( array( 
                'taxonomy'     => $field['taxonomy'],
                'orderby'      => @$field['orderby'],
                'hide_empty'   => 0,
                'hierarchical' => 1,
                'selected'     => @$field['value'],
                'name'         => @$field['name'],
                'class'        => 'ap-form-control',
                'id'           => @$field['name'],
                'echo'         => false
    ) );

    $this->output .= $taxonomies;

    $this->error_messages();

    if ( ! $this->field['show_desc_tip'] ) {
        $this->desc();
    }

    $this->output .= '</div>';
}
```

But I do NOT want to be manually changing this line of code. How do I specifically override this using code snippets plugin or `functions.php`? with `add_action` or `remove_action` combination?

Answer (score 0):

So you can't change code at random like this. If you need to change some behavior, then the plugin author needs to give you hooks - either filters or actions. If the plugin author didn't provide you with the right hooks, then you can't change the behavior, unfortunately.

You can see in the plugin code calls to `do_action` or `apply_filters` - those will tell you what kind of hooks the plugin developer put in place.

Your only "clean" options if you *don't* have access to hooks, are to:

- ask the plugin author to allow some customization of the taxonomy used - she will decide how to best do this, through hooks or plugin settings, or...
- write or hire someone to write your own plugin

**UPDATE**

So since this is open source code, what you *can* do is [fork the code](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/), and then make your modification in your own copy. Make sure to change the plugin's author and urls however, so you don't mistakingly update the plugin down the road and erase your changes!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to this.  I know it works if I change the code directly.  How do I know if this is available with do_action or apply_filters?  Do I just grep for that or is it in the same file?  This is open source.  The file is here - https://github.com/anspress/anspress/blob/b2db5dcb68509340e856809f285ecd24711fbe49/includes/class/form.php and its line 454 I'm trying to change.

Comment: Right, so as I said, you'd want to look for `do_action` or `apply_filters` in the plugin's code, around the area where you want to do your change. Doesn't seem to be in this one though. However, if this is open source, available on github, that gives you another option - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I fork the code then how do I get create and get the updated resulting zip file that would be associated with the plugin?  Or what is the best way to get the forked code into my wordpress site.

Comment: Once you have forked the repository, you can download your own copy and modify the source code. Then you can either upload the plugin folder to your website's wp-content/plugins directory, or zip your folder, and install it through WordPress' plugins "Add new" page.